# I want to create autocomplete select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html code is:

```
<select class="form-control" id="city" style="width:100%; margin-left:2%;">
        <option>Sonal</option>
        <option>abcd</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>aaaa</option>
    </select>
```

What i want:
  If i want to select abcd.
  Then there will be two type of selection method.

- first click on drop down and select one option.
- second type a key in select box then the related answer will be filter.

  ex: when we type 'a' in select box then two option must filter in dropdown.

  1.abcd
  2.aaaa

Comment: Hi sonal,

If you want to use jQuery use jQuery Autocomplete

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) which gives all the flexibility for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these demo fiddles

[Demo fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/eHPzy/38/) and this [Demo Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/TrRMG/15/)

The idea is to rebind the values in the select list with the option having the filter text.

```
$('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value).attr('rel', option.rel)
```

**Refrences**

http://dragonfruitdevelopment.com/filter-a-select-menu-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem your answer is `<datalist>` controll

here is an example from w3

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

it is a combination of an input and a dropdown menue in wich user can write in and dropdowns are filtered...

Comment: The short answer is: not to use it, because its implementation is limited, inconsistent and no styling adjustments features.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*This is a generical editable select, with a function can control all editableselect in a html or php page */  

//html
<input type="text"  name="maquina" id="maquinain" syze="30"/>
<input type="button" class="btnselect" id="maquina" value="v"/>
<div class="select" id="maquinadiv">
    <div class="suggest-element" id="something">something</div>
    <div class="suggest-element" id="something1">something1</div>
    <div class="suggest-element" id="something2">something2</div>
    <div class="suggest-element" id="something3">something3</div>

</div>

//css

        .suggest-element{
            margin-left:5px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .select {
            position:absolute;
            z-index: 100;
            width:350px;
            border:1px solid black;
            display:none;
            background-color: white;
        }

//javascrip-jquery

$('.btnselect').click(function(){

    //get input and div
    var inp = $(this).attr('id')+"in";
    var div = $(this).attr('id')+"div";

    //show the div
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';

    //click in select
    $('.suggest-element').click(function(){
        //get id of the click element
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //Edit the input with the click element data
        document.getElementById(inp).value=id;
        //hide the div
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
     });

 });
```